# Find the limit of the expression $2^{n+1}\sqrt{2-t_n}$ as $n\to\infty$, where $t_n=\sqrt{2+t_{n-1}}$

Tags: limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this series of square root of twos equal $\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85217/why-is-this-series-of-square-root-of-twos-equal-pi)

Find the limit of the expression $2^{n+1}\sqrt{2-t_n}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $t_1=\sqrt{2}$, $t_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, $t_3=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$ and so on.

Comment: What is the context? What have you tried? Where did the question come from?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85217/why-is-this-series-of-square-root-of-twos-equal-pi/85219).

Comment: The answer for $n = 10$ is, 3.1415923455701177423403759941574

Comment: Quote: *What is the context? What have you tried? Where did the question come from?* Unquote.

Answer (score 3):

> The result is a "clever" disguise of the double-angle formulas.

Note that, if $t_n=2\cos(2u)$ for some $n$ and $u$ then $t_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+2\cos(2u)}=2\cos(u)$ (*recall that, for every $v$, $\cos(2v)=2\cos^2(v)-1$*). Hence, if $t_0=2\cos(u)$ for some $u$, then $t_n=2\cos(u/2^n)$ for every $n$.

Call $x_n=2^{n+1}\sqrt{2-t_n}$, then $x_n=2^{n+1}\sqrt{2-2\cos(u/2^n)}=2^{n+2}\sin(u/2^{n+1})$ (*recall that, for every $v$, $\cos(2v)=1-2\sin^2(v)$*), and in particular, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=2u$ (*recall that $\sin(v)\sim v$ when $v\to0$*).

If $t_1=\sqrt2$, then $u/2=\pi/4$ hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

$L_n = 2^{n+1} \sqrt{2-t_n}$. Then $L_n = 2^{n+1} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2+t_{n-1}}}$. Now $$2 - \sqrt{2+t_{n-1}} = \dfrac{4 - (2+t_{n-1})}{2 + \sqrt{2+t_{n-1}}} = \dfrac{2-t_{n-1}}{2 + t_n} = \dfrac{2-t_{n-1}}{t_{n+1}^2}$$
Hence, $$L_n = 2^{n+1} \sqrt{\dfrac{2-t_{n-1}}{t_{n+1}^2}} = \dfrac{2L_{n-1}}{t_{n+1}}$$
We have $L_0 = 2 \sqrt{2}$. Hence,
$$L_n = \dfrac{2}{t_{n+1}} \cdot \dfrac{2}{t_{n}} \cdot \dfrac{2}{t_{n-1}} \cdots \dfrac{2}{t_{2}} L_0 = \dfrac{2^n}{\displaystyle \prod_{k=2}^{n+1} t_k} 2 \sqrt{2} = 2 \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} t_k}$$
Hence, we need to evaluate $$S_n = \dfrac{\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n t_k}{2^n}$$
Recall that $t_n \uparrow 2$. Let $t_ n = 2 \cos(\theta_n)$. We then have
$$\cos(\theta_{n+1}) = \dfrac{t_{n+1}}2 = \dfrac{\sqrt{2+t_n}}2 = \dfrac{\sqrt{2+2 \cos(\theta_n)}}2 = \cos(\theta_n/2)$$
Hence, we get that
$$\cos(\theta_{n+1}) = \cos(\theta_1/2^n)$$
Hence, $$S_n = \dfrac{\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n t_k}{2^n} = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos(\theta_1/2^k) = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sin(\theta_1/2^{n-1})\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos(\theta_1/2^k)}{\sin(\theta_1/2^{n-1})} = \dfrac1{2^n} \dfrac{\sin(2\theta_1)}{\sin(\theta_1/2^{n-1})}$$
Note that $\cos(\theta_1) = \dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$, which implies $\theta_1 = \dfrac{\pi}4$. Hence,
$$S_n = \dfrac1{2^n \sin(\pi/2^{n+1})}$$ Hence, $S_n \to \dfrac2{\pi}$. Hence, $$L_n \to \pi$$