# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt2}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt2}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}$.

By geometry method, I know that this is $\pi$. But is there algebraic method to find this
?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the geometry method? Circumference approximated by a $2^n-$gon?

Comment: You're right. ${}$

Comment: That would suggest that you can use $\lim \frac{\sin x } {x} = 1 = \lim \frac{\tan x} { x} $, with the same working as the circumference method.

Comment: You can check the expression is in fact $2^{n+1} \sin \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$ (by induction using trigonometric formulae) and compute the limit that way. Would that count as an algebraic method ?

Comment: @JoelCohen Post that as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this series of square root of twos equal $\pi$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85217/why-is-this-series-of-square-root-of-twos-equal-pi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $2=4\cos^{2}{\theta}$
we get
$$\underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt2}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}=4\left|\sin{\frac{\theta}{2^n}}\right|$$

And as $n \longrightarrow \infty$ ,$\frac{\theta}{2^n} \longrightarrow 0$. Hence $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}2^n\sin{\frac{\theta}{2^n}}=\theta$

$\text{Limit}=|4\theta|$

As $\cos{\theta}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ we have $\theta=\pm \frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$ $\quad ,n \in \mathrm{I}$

Here we take $\theta =\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$ (To know why please refer the note at the bottom) .

Hence the value of limit is $\pi$

---

**Note**: the reason why $\theta=\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$ only.

We know that by the definition of square-root function $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ using the same reasoning. We have $\sqrt{2+2\cos{x}}=2\cos{\frac{x}{2}}$ iff $\cos{\frac{x}{2}}\ge 0 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{2}\in \left[2n\pi,\frac{\left(4n+1\right)\pi}{2}\right] \cup \left[\frac{\left(4n-1\right)\pi}{2},2n\pi\right] ,n\in \mathbb{I}$.

As we applied the process for $n$ times for every whole number $j \le n$ we need to have the following inequality $\cos{\frac{x}{2^j}}\ge 0 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{2^j}\in \left[2N\pi,\frac{\left(4N+1\right)\pi}{2}\right] \cup \left[\frac{\left(4N-1\right)\pi}{2},2N\pi\right] ,N\in \mathbb{I}$.

Now it is easy to reason out that our $\theta$ must belong to the interval $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Comment: Are you claiming that limit simply doesn't exist?

Comment: @Kaster. Sorry I finally reasoned out why should omit the rest of the values other than $\frac{\pi}{4}$. I will post it in detail now.

Comment: In fact, you could've taken $\theta = \frac \pi 4$ explicitly. All your calculations would hold anyway.

Comment: @Kaster, yes you are right. But to some extend that raises a doubt in a reader (including me) why I tried $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and why not $\frac{9\pi}{4}$.