# Find the value of : $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2a)^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a(a-1)+\sqrt{a(a-1)+\cdots}}}$

Tags: limits, nested-radicals

find the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(2a)^{\frac{n}{2}}\underbrace{\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a(a-1)+\sqrt{a(a-1)+\cdots}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}$$

> My try: 
>   I know this [Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt2}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428046/find-lim-n-to-infty2n-underbrace-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-dots-sqrt2?rq=1)

and this problem just

> $$\underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt2}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}=4\left|\sin{\frac{\theta}{2^n}}\right|$$
>   so
>   follow this limit is easy to find it.

But
$$\underbrace{\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a(a-1)+\sqrt{a(a-1)+\cdots}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}=?$$

Answer (score 3):

The answer given was completely wrong.

Comment: The formula for $L$ is incorrect - it should be $L=\sqrt{a(a-1)+L}$ - and it's not clear why $L=a$ should be inacceptable - it's very easy to see that the sequence does in fact converge to $a$ when $a$ is positive and large.

Comment: Yes, this is wrong.  For $a=2$, the answer is $\pi$, not infinity, and it was just demonstrated [in the other thread about this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983604/lim-n-to-infty-sqrt6-n-underbrace-sqrt3-sqrt6-sqrt6-dotsb-sqrt) that the limit is finite for all $a>2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution Outline** (I will leave the details for you to fill).

So, we consider this: $$ (2a)^{\frac{n}{2}}\underbrace{\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a(a-1)+\sqrt{a(a-1)+\cdots}}}}_{n \textrm{ square roots}}, $$ where $n \to \infty$. We assert that the number of square roots that are nested is indeed just infinity. So, we consider this: $$ S = \sqrt{a(a-1)+\sqrt{a(a-1)+\cdots}}, $$ where, here, there are an infinite number of nested square roots. Then, $$S^2=a(a-1)+S.$$Then, you can solve for $S$ using the quadratic formula. our original expression is, remember the following: $$ (2a)^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{a-S}. $$You can get $S$ using the quadratic formula and substitute into this expression. Then, finding the limit of the resulting expression will not be trivial but it won't be impossible either.

Comment: If I may please ask $-$ why did I get 2 upvotes on this on the same morning despite the 3 upvotes and the bounty?

Comment: Two downvotes, you mean?  It might be because this thread was [just linked to elsewhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983604/lim-n-to-infty-sqrt6-n-underbrace-sqrt3-sqrt6-sqrt6-dotsb-sqrt).  In short, your solution appears to be completely wrong; the quadratic formula yields $S=a$, which should imply (by your reasoning) that the entire expression is zero.  But it's not; the difficulty here is in determining _how quickly_ $S$ approaches zero, and comparing that with the multiplying factor.

Comment: This problem is _hard_, or at least, quite a bit harder than the approaches in this thread seem to imply.  When $a=2$, the limit is actually $\pi$, and it is not clear how one can get there with things like the quadratic formula.  For $a\neq 2$, it is very possible that there is a positive limit for this sequence, but without a closed form.

Comment: @Slade Yes, I meant 2 downvotes. Thanks for the explanation. 2 upvotes. :)