# Identify $C\approx1.29$ the limit of $\left(\pi - 2^n \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt 2}}\right)\cdot 4^n$

Tags: limits, pi, constants

It is easy to prove the existence of the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\pi - 2^n \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt 2}} \right) 4^n = C = 1.29\ldots$$

I am not confident about more digits but this number seems familiar as if it has a closed form or it has appeared elsewhere.

Is it possible to find a closed form for $C$ ?
Can we prove that $C$ is irrational ?

$C$ seems close to $(5/4 + 4/3)/2 = 31/24$.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/428116/253273) may help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, let's try to make some sense out of it.
$$\sqrt2=2\cos{\pi\over4}$$
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}=\sqrt{2+2\cos{\pi\over4}}=2\cos{\pi\over8}$$
$$\sqrt{2+\dots\sqrt2}=2\cos{\pi\over2^n}$$
(I may be off by 1, since you never defined what $n$ is. Whatever.)

Now we put one minus on top of that chain of pluses.
$$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\dots\sqrt2}}=\sqrt{2-2\cos{\pi\over2^n}}=2\sin{\pi\over2^{n+1}}$$
Now the Taylor series kicks in.
$$\sin{\pi\over2^{n+1}}={\pi\over2^{n+1}}-{1\over6}\cdot\left({\pi\over2^{n+1}}\right)^3+o\left({1\over2^{3n}}\right)$$
$$4^n\left(\pi-2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\dots\sqrt2}}\right)=4^n\cdot{1\over6}\cdot{\pi^3\over2^{2n+2}}+o(1)={\pi^3\over24}+o(1)$$
So $\pi^3\over24$ is your limit. (BTW, yes, it's irrational and even transcendental.) Considering that $\pi^3\approx31.0063$, your approximation was indeed pretty close.

Comment: Could you say how you obtained the second equation?

Comment: Why, that's the double angle formula applied in reverse. $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$, hence $\sqrt{2+2\cos2x}=\sqrt{2+2\cos^2x-2\sin^2x}=\sqrt{4\cos^2x}=2\cos x$.

Comment: The power of Ivan and Taylor !! :)

Comment: I have seen pi^3 / 24 before as Some Nice integral or zeta like thing... Thinking about it :)