# About $\sqrt[k]{l + \sqrt[k]{l + \sqrt[k]{l + ...}}} $ asymptotics

Tags: limits, asymptotics, closed-form, nested-radicals, constants

Consider simple nested radicals

More precisely Let

$$ K > 1 , 1 \leq l $$

$$X(j,K) = X_\infty(j,K)$$

$$X_0(j,K) = a(j,K)$$

$$X_n(j,K) = \sqrt[k]{j + X_{n-1}(j,K)}$$

$$Y(j,K) = \frac{j + X_{\infty}(j,K) }{X_{\infty}(j,K) }$$

Ofcourse we have $X_{\infty}(j,K) ^k = j + X_{\infty}(j,K)$.

Then we have the limit as $n$ goes to infinity

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (X_{\infty}(j,K) - X_n(j,K))(Y(j,k) k)^n = C(j,K)$$

And as $K$ goes to infinity

$$C(j,\infty) = (j+1) \ln(\frac{j+1}{j})$$

——

Perhaps a proof sketch of the last statement

Let $f_k(x) = \sqrt[k]{1+x}$ for $x \ge 0$ and $k > 1$.
Let $\alpha_k$ the unique positive fixpoint  of $f_k$ (it is the positive root of $\alpha_k^k = \alpha_k+1$).
Define $c_{k,n} = (\alpha_k - f_k^{n-1}(1))(f_k'(\alpha_k))^{-n}$ for $n \ge 1$.

Now constant $C_k$ is defined by $C_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} c_{k,n}$, and we want to give an estimation of $C_k/c_{k,1}$.

We have $c_{k,{n+1}}/c_{k,n} = f_k'(\alpha_k)^{-1}(f_k(\alpha_k) - f_k(f_k^{n-1}(1)))/(\alpha_k - f_k^{n-1}(1)) = f_k'(\alpha_k)^{-1}f_k'(z_{k,n})$ for some $f_k^{n-1}(1) \le z_{k,n} \le \alpha_k$.

Since $f_k'$ is decreasing, we obtain 
 $1 \le c_{k,n+1}/c_{k,n} \le f_k'(f_k^{n-1}(1))f_k'(\alpha_k)^{-1}$

Some crude estimates gives us $\alpha_k \ge f_k^n(1) \ge \alpha_k - (\alpha_k - 1)f_k'(1)^n$,
and then ($f''_k$ is increasing), $f'_k(\alpha_k) \le f_k'(f_k^n(1)) \le f_k'(\alpha_k) -  (\alpha_k-1)f'_k(1)^nf_k''(1)$,
and finally $1 \le c_{k,n+1}/c_{k,n} \le 1 + (\alpha_k-1)f'_k(1)^{n-1}(-f''_k(1))f_k'(\alpha_k)^{-1} $.

Using $1+x \le \exp(x)$ and taking the product,
we obtain $1 \le C_k/c_{k,1} \le \exp((\alpha_k-1)(-f''_k(1))f'_k(\alpha_k)^{-1}/(1-f'_k(1))) $

---

Since $\alpha_k = 1 + \log 2/k + O(k^{-2})$, we have

$\alpha_k-1 \sim  \log2 / k$
$f'_k(\alpha_k) = \alpha_k(1 + \alpha_k)^{-1}/k \sim 1/2k$
$c_{k,1} = (1/2)(\alpha_k-1)f'_k(\alpha_k)^{-1} \sim (1/2)(\log 2/k)(2k) = \log 2$
$f_k'(1) = 2^{1/k-1} \frac 1k \sim 1/2k$
$f''_k(1) = 2^{1/k-2} \frac 1k (\frac 1k -1) \sim -1/4k$
$(\alpha_k-1)(-f''_k(1))f'_k(\alpha_k)^{-1}/(1-f'_k(1)) \sim \log 2/2k \to 0$

This shows that $C_k \sim c_{k,1} \to 2\log 2$

---

For the more general case, we start from $x_1 = l^{1/k} = 1 + \log(l)/k + \ldots$, while $\alpha = 1 + \log(l+1)/k + \ldots$, which are again close to each other.

$\alpha - l^{1/k} \sim \log(\frac{l+1}l)/k$
$f'(\alpha) = \alpha/k(l+\alpha) \sim 1/(l+1)k$
$c_1 = (1/2)(\alpha - l^{1/k})/f'(\alpha) \sim \frac{l+1}2\log(\frac{l+1}l)$

Since $f'(\alpha^{1/k})$ and $f''(\alpha^{1/k})$ are on the order of $1/k$, we have $C = (l+1) \log(\frac{l+1}l)$

——

Now I wonder about

$$ T(j,K) = ( C(j,K) - C(j,K-1) ) ^{-2} $$

How does $T(j,K) $ behave for large $K$ ?
I assume we have a good approximation of the form

$$ T(j,K) = v_1(j) + v_2(j) v_3(j)^K v_4(j)^{v_3(j)^K} $$

Where $v_i(j)$ are constants depending only on $j$.

Is this true and what are (some of) the closed forms of the v_i ??

Notice for $j = 1 $ this is related to the Paris constant.

Are there closed forms for -say- $v_2(1)$ or $ v_3(1) $ or are they as “ hopeless “ as  the Paris constant itself ?

I believe in the past I have asked somewhat similar questions imho , and Taylor series were useful. In particular I mean this here

[Identify $C\approx1.29$ the limit of $\left(\pi - 2^n \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt 2}}\right)\cdot 4^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885794/identify-c-approx1-29-the-limit-of-left-pi-2n-sqrt2-sqrt2-cdots-sq)

Not sure if that is relevant or helpful. 
I link it anyway.