# there is any relation between $\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$ or a generic polygon?

Tags: geometry, pi, polyhedra, polygons

I'm a programmer, I'm always looking for new formulas and new way of computing things, to satisfy my curiosity I would like to know if there are any formulas, or I should say *equalities*, that make use of both $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ .

I would also like to know if it's possible to generalize this relatively to any n-sided polygon ( even a 3D figure ), $\sqrt{2}$ that usually appears in quadrilaterals only.

Of course I would like to know about any possible domain, but since we should start from something, I would say that the domain of polygons and polyhedron triggers my interest in the first place.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85217/why-is-this-series-of-square-root-of-twos-equal-pi) seems relevant.

Comment: Apparently Plato thought that $\pi=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, exactly. In fact $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ approximates $\pi$ to within two-thousandths of a percent, which is not bad.

Comment: @DavidMitra it's basically the top rated answer at the moment, if I'm not mistaking, nice to read a longer explanation.

Comment: @DavidH it this linked to some study in geometry ?

Comment: @user2485710 It's based on simple mensuration formulas for plane shapes. The area of a unit circle is $\pi$. An inscribed octagon inside the circle will have area $2\sqrt{2}$. A circumscribed hexagon around the circle will have area $2\sqrt{3}$. The average of the areas of the hexagon and octagon is then $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @DavidH so there is a generic formula to plot the perimeter, or the vertices or the area of an N-sided polygon using trigonometry ?

Comment: @user2485710 For regular polygons, yes. [See the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Area).

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85217/why-is-this-series-of-square-root-of-twos-equal-pi?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

$$
\pi = 2\sqrt 2 \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}} \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}} \cdots.
$$

Comment: let me guess, it's some kind of approximation of $\pi$ related to some polygon ?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty trivial, but for the sake of completeness:

$$\sin\frac\pi4=\cos\frac\pi4=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

Here I'd say the $\frac\pi4$ relates to a regular octagon, or the canonical eighth root of unity, so yes, it generalizes to other regular $n$-gons, resulting in other algebraic numbers for the sine and cosine of the corresponding angles resp. the real and imaginary part of the corresponding root of unity.

If you want to go 3D, you'd probably start using Euler angles and quaternions, but I'll not go into this.

Answer (score 2):

Stirling's approximation:
$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$

Comment: there are other uses beside the approximation of a factorial for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had fun doing that back in the days; lots of paper and the smallest mistake would end in chaos. I felt I had discovered something in the end :)
(Note: bug in the code snippet: k=3 is skipped; the line "if k>3 then" should be "if k>2 then".)

> I was $17$ years old when I took on that task, alone at home with a lot of scratch paper. I remember the wow effect when the pattern emerged. It was about expressing PI in function of the square root of $2$. Focus recommended!
> In the last $35$ years, I mentioned it $3$ or $4$ times and it never raised much interest, probably because expressing an irrational number in function of another no more rational one does not make sense :).
> In iteration $3$, the function starts to look like the precedent one; then it's obvious between $3$ and $5$ and it goes on, making it easy to program. It will get closer to PI before breaking due to the variable's limitations. Here a code snippet (too) quickly put together for demo purposes.

[image]
[image]

Original post: https://www.facebook.com/yazel.boudour/posts/353578401680948

Answer (score 1):

$$t_n=\bigg(-\dfrac14\bigg)^n\cdot\dfrac{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}{1-2n}\qquad=>\qquad\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n=\sqrt2~,\qquad\qquad\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n^2=\dfrac4\pi$$

---

This is based on the fact that $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N{N\choose n}=2^N,~$ and $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N{N\choose n}^2={2N\choose N}.~$ Now let $N=\dfrac12$

and use the fact that $\Big(\tfrac12\Big)!=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2$ . See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), and [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

for more details.

Comment: and this is optimal for what kind of applications ?

Comment: @user2485710: None that I'm aware of. Why? Are you only interested in formulas that have practical applications? If so, then please specify that explicitly in the body of the post, by mentioning exactly what kind of applications you have in mind.

Comment: since I was mentioning geometry, polyhedron and polygons I was assuming that this had something to do with it. Anyway since there is a $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ equal to $\sqrt{2}$ maybe this can be used to approximate some computations .

Comment: Since the two constants you mention are connected to two basic geometric shapes (the unit square and the unit circle), then all formulas about them are connected to the latter as well. But not all connections are necessarily practical. Euler's and de Moivre's formulas are quite helpful in plotting regular polygons or stars, for instance, since they give the coordinates of their vertices. As far as computations are concerned, all processors know how to extract a square root, and all programming languages know the value of $\pi$, so I doubt there's any practical application there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ to calculate square roots using $\pi$.

For example, you can calculate the square root of 2 as follows:

$$\sin{(45^\circ)}=\sin{(\frac\pi4)}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$$

Therefore:

$$\sqrt2=2\cdot\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^{4x-3}}{(4x-3)!}-\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^{4x-1}}{(4x-1)!}$$

I haven't tried personally,  but I imagine you could relate a lot of square roots back to $\pi$ like this. Simply find the angle, in radians of a triangle with a side length of $\sqrt x$ and then expand by expressing the angle in terms of $\pi$ using the Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

$$\exp(i (\sqrt{2})^2 \pi)=1$$

Comment: and this wonderful thing is ... ? :D

Comment: not 100% sure if that counts, as you are using 2 (${\sqrt{2}}^2$), instead of $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Its $ e^{2\pi\cdot i} $ xD

Comment: @user2485710 This is the most beautiful formula in all mathematics, [Euler's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity).

Comment: from pragmatism to feticism in no time. Why I'm not surprised that the animation of this on the wikipedia looks like it's solving the "squaring the circle" problem.

Comment: @Asimov me neither. But if the user was unaware of the identity, then I'm glad I introduced him to it ;)

Comment: @DavidH Indeed, who can argue as to the beauty of the Euler Formulas applications.

Comment: the funny thing is, I still don't get what "transcendental" means in practical geometric terms, even after seen this, because this is the real difference between $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ and I can't visualize what this means .

Answer (score 0):

For a programmer the  [Ramanujan formula(e)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series) might be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some formulas relating $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$. Given the Riemann zeta function,

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s}$$

Let $q=e^{\pi\sqrt{2}}$. Then,

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{3}{2}\,\zeta(3) &= \frac{\pi^3}{24}\sqrt{2}-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3(q^{k}-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3(q^{2k}-1)}\\
\frac{3}{2}\,\zeta(5) &= \frac{\pi^5}{270}\sqrt{2}-4\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^5(q^{k}-1)}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^5(q^{2k}-1)}\\
\frac{9}{2}\,\zeta(7) &= \frac{41\pi^7}{37800}\sqrt{2}-8\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^7(q^{k}-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^7(q^{2k}-1)} \end{aligned}$$