# Ratio between Polygon height to perimeter.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Is there a constant ratio or linear/curvilinear set of ratios of the perimeter of an n-gon and the n-gon maximum height (eg apothem to apothem, circumscribed diameter, etc.) I've only calculated a few regular polygons:
*The triangle's ratio would be $\sqrt{2}:1$,
the square's ratio would be $4:\sqrt{2}$,
the hexagon would be $3:1$,
and the octagon would be $(2\sqrt{2}+1):1$.*
Is there an associated sequence following this pattern? If so, please share it with me.

Comment: You might want to consider the odd and even cases separately. When $n$ is even you seem to be looking at twice the circumradius (from corner to opposite corner). When $n$ is odd, you seem to be looking at the apothem plus the circumradius (from corner to opposite side; this is not really the maximum diameter of the polygon, e.g. the side of a triangle is longer than the central height). Formulas for both can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Circumradius and use trigonometry

Comment: You might like to check out https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1)**  The ratio P/h of perimeter (P) to height (h) where we define h as the diameter of the circumcircle (or vertex to opposite vertex of an even numbered regular polygon) the formula is: $$ P/h = N  \sin(\pi/N)$$ where N is the number of sides of the polygon.

**Method 2)**  When we define h as the diameter of the incircle (or as twice the apothem or as face to opposite face of an even numbered regular polygon) the formula is: $$ P/h = N  \tan(\pi/N)$$
**Method 3)**  When we define h as the orthogonal distance from a face to an opposite vertex of an odd numbered regular polygon (or as apothem plus circumradius) we combine the two above methods and eventually get: $$ P/h = 2 N \tan(\pi/(2 N)) $$

Here is a table of the ratios produced by the 3 methods.

| N | Method 1 | Method 2 | Method 3 | ------- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2.5980 | 5.1961 | 3.4641 | 1.4142 |
| 4 | 2.8284 | 4.0000 | 3.3137 | 2.8284 |
| 5 | 2.9389 | 3.6727 | 3.2491 | 3.0000 |
| 6 | 3.0000 | 3.4641 | 3.2154 | 3.8284 |
| 7 | 3.0371 | 3.3710 | 3.1954 |  |
| 8 | 3.0614 | 3.3137 | 3.1825 |  |

The last column is the result of converting your ratios into decimal integers.

> I've only calculated a few regular polygons: The triangle's ratio would be $\sqrt{2}:1$ , the square's ratio would be
> $4:\sqrt{2}$ , the hexagon would be $3:1$ , and the octagon would be $(2\sqrt{2}+1):1$

Your examples do not seem to concur with any of the above 3 methods, so maybe I am misunderstanding your question or misinterpreting your definitions or I have made a mistake. Perhaps you could check your figures, to see where we differ. I will try to add to this answer and edit as required in response to any edits you make to clarify the original question.

P.S. I agree with Milton that it would probably be best to treat even and odd polygons as separate cases.

P.P.S All 3 methods converge towards $\pi$ as N gets larger and so does the infinite series $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\cdots+ \sqrt 2}} = \pi$$

$$\pi = 2\sqrt 2 \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}} \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}} \cdots.$$
[See this old thread.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802751/there-is-any-relation-between-pi-sqrt2-or-a-generic-polygon) Perhaps this is the connection to the $\sqrt 2$ that you appear to be looking for...