# How to express the equations as the Square root Like?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2\sin \frac{\pi}{16}= \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$$

What law is need to be applied here? Do I have to make the $\frac{\pi}{16}$ in a form  that will be give us $\sqrt{2}$ like  sin 45 degree?

Comment: Hint: $sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - cos(x)}{2}}$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85217/why-is-this-series-of-square-root-of-twos-equal-pi/85219#85219) may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, $\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos\theta}{2}}$ and $\cos{\dfrac{\theta}
{2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos\theta}{2}}$

$\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{4}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}}{2}}$

$\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{4}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos{\theta}}{2}}}{2}}$

Putting, $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

$\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{16}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}}{2}}}{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2}$

Now, multiply both sides by $2$ to get the required equation.

$2\sin \dfrac{\pi}{16}= \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$

Comment: In general, this is not true for $-\pi < \theta < 0$, but it works for the given $\theta$.

Comment: but in this case $\theta$ is $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Where have we got the expression?

Comment: @SabbirHasan Note that $$\sin{\frac{x}{4}}=\sin{[\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}]}$$

Comment: Git you thanks. But what would we do if we have $2 \sin 11^{0} 30^{\prime}$ or $2 \cos 7 \frac{1}{2} $ , Can I do these two different type of math in the same way you did?

Comment: of course you can! $2 \cos 7 \frac{1}{2}$ is one fourth of 30 and other is the same as your question

Answer (score 3):

Call $x = \sin \frac{\pi}{16} \to 1-2x^2 = \cos \frac{\pi}{8} \to \left(1-2x^2\right)^2 = \cos^2 \frac{\pi}{8} = \dfrac{1+\cos \frac{\pi}{4}}{2} = \dfrac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4} \to 1-2x^2 = \dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} \to x^2 = \dfrac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{4} \to 2x = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$.