# I discovered a sequence that should converge to $\pi$ , but how to prove that it really converges to $\pi$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, pi

So yesterday I took paper and pencil and did some constructions of geometrical nature and I discovered a sequence that should converge to $\pi$.

It goes like this:

> Define $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ and for every other $n \in \mathbb N$ define $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$. Define $S_n=2^n \cdot \sqrt{2-a_{n-1}}$. Then we should have $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n=\pi$.

This formula (more correctly, sequence) can be seen [on this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) and is labeled with number (66) so I did not discover anything new.

I found this sequence but I did not rigorously prove that it converges to $\pi$, the story is that I saw a pattern for the first few natural numbers and then defined the expression for general $n$ and when I did that I found the sequence on the above linked page.

My question would be:

> In which way would you prove that this sequence converges to $\pi$?

Comment: A trigonometric proof is the best way, since this is related to the famous Vieta formula (look it up). Use the doulbe angle formula for the sine and cosine functions

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/85217/269624) for the exact same limit. There is a lot of answers there

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you, that looks helpful.