# What is the fastest/most efficient algorithm for estimating Euler's Constant $\gamma$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, numerical-methods, estimation, euler-mascheroni-constant

What is the fastest algorithm for estimating Euler's Constant $\gamma \approx0.57721$?

Using the definition:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{x=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}-\log n=\gamma$$

I finally get $2$ decimal places of accuracy when $n\geq180$.  The third correct decimal place only comes when $n \geq638$.  Clearly, this method is not very efficient (it can be expensive to compute $\log$).

What is the best method to use to numerically estimate $\gamma$ efficiently?

Comment: The website http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/  not only has programs but has record setting number of digits computation lists for $\,\pi,\gamma\,$ and other constants.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The paper "On the computation of the Euler constant $\gamma$" by Ekatharine A. Karatsuba, in Numerical Algorithms 24(2000) 83-97, has a lot to say about this.  This [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1019137125281) might work for you.

In particular, the author shows that for $k\ge 1$,
$$ 
\gamma= 1-\log k \sum_{r=1}^{12k+1} \frac{ (-1)^{r-1} k^{r+1}}{(r-1)!(r+1)} +
\sum_{r=1}^{12k+1} \frac{ (-1)^{r-1} k^{r+1} }{(r-1)! (r+1)^2}+\mbox{O}(2^{-k})$$

and more explicitly
$$\begin{align*}
-\frac{2}{(12k)!} - 2k^2 e^{-k} \le \gamma 
-1+&\log k \sum_{r=1}^{12k+1} \frac{ (-1)^{r-1} k^{r+1}}{(r-1)!(r+1)}
- \sum_{r=1}^{12k+1} \frac{ (-1)^{r-1} k^{r+1} }{(r-1)! (r+1)^2}\\
&\le \frac{2}{(12k)!} + 2k^2 e^{-k}\end{align*}$$
for $k\ge 1$.

Since the series has fast convergence, you can use these to get good approximations to $\gamma$ fairly quickly.

Comment: ... not to be confused with [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatolii_Alexeevitch_Karatsuba) of [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks! Here are the results from this series to those who are interested (Sorry about the lack of line breaks):       k=1, sum=0.7965995992978246, error=0.21938393439629178.  
k=5, sum=0.5892082678451087, error=0.011992602943575847.  
k=10, sum=0.5773243590712589, error=1.086941697260313E-4.   
k=15, sum=0.5772165124955206, error=8.47593987773898E-7.   
Great series!

Comment: @user2468: Ekatherina Karatsuba is Anatolii Karatsuba's daughter.

Comment: @Argon, what an amazing coincidence! The continued fraction algorithm I posted for $k=15$ has almost the same error $8.4354308339798 \cdot 10^{-7}$

Comment: However, in my case it actually means step $15$, not step $12 \cdot 15+1$

Answer (score 32):

I like
 $$ \gamma = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \left( \; \; 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1 } - \cdots - \frac{1}{n^2 }  - \frac{1}{n^2 + 1 } - \cdots  - \frac{1}{n^2 + n} \; \; \right) $$
because it needs no logarithm and the error is comparable to the final term used.

```
       n                sum                 error                    n^2 * error
       1          0.5                    0.07721566490153287       0.07721566490153287
      10          0.5757019096925315     0.001513755209001322      0.1513755209001322
     100          0.5771991634147917    1.650148674114948e-05      0.1650148674114948
    1000          0.5772154984013406    1.665001923001341e-07      0.1665001923001341
   10000          0.5772156632363485    1.665184323762503e-09      0.1665184323762503
```

I found this formula on page 82, the January 2012 issue (volume 119, number 1) of the M. A. A. American Mathematical Monthly. It was sent in by someone named Jouzas Juvencijus Macys, possibly for the Problems and Solutions section. He stopped the sum at $-1/n^2.$ I noticed that the error would be minimized by continuing the sum to $-1/(n^2 + n).$ If you want, you can add a single term $1/(6 n^2)$ to get the error down to $n^{-3}.$

$$ \gamma = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \frac{1}{6n^2} + \left( \; \; 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1 } - \cdots - \frac{1}{n^2 }  - \frac{1}{n^2 + 1 } - \cdots  - \frac{1}{n^2 + n} \; \; \right) $$

```
       n                sum                 error              
       1          0.6666666666666666   -0.08945100176513376
      10          0.5773685763591982   -0.0001529114576653834
     100          0.5772158300814584   -1.651799255153463e-07
    1000          0.5772156650680073   -1.664743898288634e-10
   10000          0.5772156649030152   -1.482369782479509e-12
```

EDIT, December 2013. I just got a nice note, with English preprint, from Prof. Macys. [The original article is in Lithuanian in 2008](http://www.knygos.ktu.lt/main.php?ID=64&StrukturaID=12&KatID=4920). [A Russian version](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=9386&option_lang=eng) and matching [English translation](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/11006) are both 2013: the Springer website is not quite up to Volume 94, number 5, pages 45-50. The English language journal is called Mathematical Notes. Oh, the title is "On the Euler-Mascheroni constant."

If desired, you can put two correction terms to get the error down to $n^{-4}.$

$$ \gamma = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \;  \frac{-1}{6n^3} +\frac{1}{6n^2} + \left( \; \; 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1 } - \cdots - \frac{1}{n^2 }   - \cdots  - \frac{1}{n^2 + n} \; \; \right) $$

```
 10  0.5772019096925316  1.375520900126492e-05  
100  0.5772156634147917  1.486741174616668e-09 
600  0.5772156649003506  1.182276498923329e-12
```

Comment: The behavior of the approximation error for Macys's series makes it a good candidate for extrapolation methods. Richardson worked nicely (as in the answer I gave), but maybe other methods can do better...

Comment: The first expression may be written as a series:

$$
\gamma= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{n}-\sum_{j=n(n-1)+1}^{n(n+1)} \frac{1}{j}\right)
$$

http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591256/134791

Comment: that leads to a closed form for $\psi\left(z+1\right)$
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357091/re-expressing-the-digamma

Comment: Changing the weight of the last term also gets the error down to $n^{-4}$
$$lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 2H_n-\frac{1}{6}H_{n^2+n-1}-\frac{5}{6}H_{n^2+n}\right)$$
because this cancels two terms in the asymptotic expansion. The results are very similar without additional terms, just weight 5/6 for 1/(n^2+n):                                       
10 0.577217061207682 1.39630614900659 E-6
100 0.577215665064940 1.63407322137730 E-10
600 0.577215664901661 1.28173793434336 E-13

Answer (score 13):

A good place for fast evaluation of constants is Gourdon and Sebah's ['Numbers, constants and computation'](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/constants.html).

They got $108\cdot 10^6$ digits for $\gamma$ in 1999 (see the end of their 2004 article ['The Euler constant'](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Gamma/gamma.pdf)) and propose a free program for high precision evaluation of various constants ['PiFast'](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/PiProgram/pifast.html).

On his page of constants Simon Plouffe has [Euler's constants](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/constants/gamma.txt) to 10^6 digits (the file looks much smaller sorry...) using Brent's splitting algorithm (see the 1980 paper of Brent ['Some new algorithms for high-precision computation of Euler’s constant'](http://cr.yp.to/bib/1980/brent-gamma.pdf) or more recently 3.1 in Haible and Papanikolaou's ['Fast multiprecision evaluation of series of rational numbers'](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/binsplit.pdf)).

It seems that the 1999 record was broken in 2009 by A. Yee & R. Chan with 29,844,489,545 digits ['Mathematical Constants - Billions of Digits'](http://www.numberworld.org/digits/) (warning: the torrent file proposed there is more than 11Gb large! An earlier 52Mb file of 'only' 116 million digits is available [here](http://www.numberworld.org/euler116m.html) using the method proposed by Gourdon and Sebah).

Comment: The `2.3  Exponential integral methods` chapter on the [2nd link](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Gamma/gamma.pdf) is really great. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

(**N.B.** The previous version of this answer featured both the Brent-McMillan algorithm and the acceleration of Macys's series; I have decided to move the Brent-McMillan material into a new answer in the interest of having only one method per answer.)

---

The convergence properties of Macys's series in Will's answer can be improved a fair bit, if you're willing to devote some amount of computational effort; due to the $n^{-2}$ behavior of the error, one obvious choice for a convergence acceleration method is Richardson extrapolation.

Skipping some hairy details (which I might include later if I find time, but see [Marchuk/Shaidurov](http://books.google.com/books/?hl=en&id=V-hhGQAACAAJ) if you must), the working formula is

$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty} G_n=2\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{n-i} i^{2n+2}}{(n+i+1)!(n-i+1)!}\left(\sum_{k=i+1}^{i(i+1)} \frac1{k}-\sum_{k=1}^i \frac1{k}\right)$$

Here are some sample results:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}n&G_n&\gamma-G_n\\10&0.577210083083&5.581818\times10^{-6}\\50&0.577215659731&5.170456\times10^{-9}\\100&0.577215664665&2.362333\times10^{-10}\\200&0.577215664891&1.061648\times10^{-11}\\250&0.577215664898&3.902515\times10^{-12}\\300&0.577215664900&1.721878\times10^{-12}\\350&0.577215664901&8.618620\times10^{-13}\end{array}$$

For higher precision, there isn't much of an improvement; I would still recommend Brent-McMillan if one needs many digits of $\gamma$.

Comment: On another note: I also like using convergence acceleration methods (e.g. Cohen-Rodriguez Villegas-Zagier or Levin) on the following alternating series for the Stieltjes constants: $$\gamma_n=\frac{(\log\,2)^n}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}B_{n+1}(\log_2 k)$$ where $B_n(x)$ is a Bernoulli polynomial, and $\gamma=\gamma_0$

Comment: The Macys acceleration is very nice. How soon do we get error below $1.532860 \times 10^{−12},$ so that we see $G_n$ beginning with $0.5772156649...?$

Comment: I just got a note from Prof. Macys. I think he would like this version; his interest seems to be in keeping to rational functions of $n,$ which i rather like as well.

Answer (score 10):

Finch's *Mathematical Constants* mentions these papers:

- D. W. DeTemple, [A quicker convergence to Euler's constant](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324300), Amer. Math. Monthly (1993) 468-470.
- T. Negoi, [A faster convergence to Euler's constant](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3620963), Math. Gazette 83 (1999) 487-489.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, the convergence of the Karatsuba series presented in Matthew's answer can be improved. This time, the geometric behavior of the error (as can be ascertained from the bounds presented) can be exploited through the use of the [Shanks transformation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1956-0084056-6). (Richardson can be made to work here as well, but the results are not as spectacular.)

Letting

$$\varepsilon_0^{(k)}=1-\log(k+1) \sum_{r=1}^{12k+13} \frac{ (-k)^{r+1}}{(r-1)!(r+1)} + \sum_{r=1}^{12k+13} \frac{ (-k)^{r+1} }{(r-1)!(r+1)^2}$$

Wynn's version of the Shanks transformation uses the recursion

$$\varepsilon_{k+1}^{(n)}=\varepsilon_{k-1}^{(n+1)}+\frac1{\varepsilon_{k}^{(n+1)}-\varepsilon_k^{(n)}}$$

It would seem that a two-dimensional array would be required for implementation, but one can arrange things such that only a one-dimensional array is required, through clever overwriting. Here is a *Mathematica* routine to demonstrate:

```
wynnEpsilon[seq_?VectorQ] := Module[{n = Length[seq], ep, res, v, w},
  res = {};
  Do[
   ep[k] = seq[[k]];
   w = 0;
   Do[
    v = w; w = ep[j];
    ep[j] = 
     v + (If[Abs[ep[j + 1] - w] > 10^-(Precision[w]), ep[j + 1] - w, 
         10^-(Precision[w])])^-1;
    , {j, k - 1, 1, -1}];
   res = {res, ep[If[OddQ[k], 1, 2]]};
   , {k, n}];
  Flatten[res]
  ]
```

(actually the same as the routine presented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36066)).

Here's a comparison of Karatsuba's series, with and without Shanks transformation:

```
gamprox = Table[N[1 - Log[k]*Sum[(-k)^(r + 1)/((r + 1)*(r - 1)!),
            {r, 1, 12*k + 1}] + Sum[(-k)^(r + 1)/((r + 1)^2*(r - 1)!),
            {r, 1, 12*k + 1}], 50], {k, 30}];

trans = wynnEpsilon[gamprox];

gamprox[[20]] - EulerGamma // N
1.31827*10^-7

trans[[20]] - EulerGamma // N
6.49869*10^-18

Last[gamprox] - EulerGamma // N
9.96301*10^-12

Last[trans] - EulerGamma // N
2.07059*10^-27
```

Not too shabby, in my humble opinion...

Comment: graeat jobs works perfectly, I  used works with levin transform could please let the code  implementation for Mathematica using the recursive form for the Levin u trasnform algorithm.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I quite like the [Brent-McMillan algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1980-0551307-4) myself (which is based on the relationships between the Euler-Mascheroni constant and modified Bessel functions):

$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathscr{G}_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n^k}{k!}\right)^2 (H_k-\log\,n)}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n^k}{k!}\right)^2}$$

where $H_k=\sum\limits_{j=1}^k \frac1{j}$ is a harmonic number.

It requires the use of a logarithm, but the algorithm is quite simple and reasonably efficient (in particular, we have the inequality $0 < \mathscr{G}_n-\gamma < \pi\exp(-4n)$).

Here's some *Mathematica* code for the Brent-McMillan algorithm (which should be easily translatable to your language of choice):

```
n = 50;
a = u = N[-Log[n], n]; b = v = 1;
i = 1;
While[True,
  k = (n/i)^2;
  a *= k; b *= k;
  a += b/i;
  If[u + a == u || v + b == v, Break[]];
  u += a; v += b;
  i++
  ];
u/v
```

The integer parameter `n` controls the accuracy; very roughly, the algorithm will yield `n-2` or so correct digits.

The Brent-McMillan paper also presents more elaborate schemes for computing $\gamma$, such as

$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n^k}{k!}\right)^2 (H_k-\log\,n)}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n^k}{k!}\right)^2}-\frac{\frac1{4n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k)!^3}{k!^4 (16n)^{2k}}}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n^k}{k!}\right)^2\right)^2}$$

but I have no experience in using them.

Comment: $\pi e^{-4n}$ is a pretty fast rate of convergence. (+1) Have you investigated the computational efficiency in terms of how many multiplications and additions would be needed to get a given accuracy?

Comment: Not in full, but there's something to be said about it being the method of choice for arbitrary-precision computation of $\gamma$ in computing environments like Maple and *Mathematica*.

Comment: Here's a live [Python version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUdtqhDAQffcrBvqibusm8V4Q-uB_lKwbJawmEqPs53eMq7bQSAhzLnMmsTV6gLto5MB7kMOojYX6VfIJ6nfohG20suJpwWtXtbTCWK37adc3elZIel8SZYY31ruLFsTcC_Pd8WHg_l120k5VTIJPD3BtNVSAjhcZOKKxT0TPSD-AHY9GIxokX94LMGQcqRCt_7ThiMy4P1TUK3_DblgvTkmD3dlqAxKH2K6AxDbeuh4o9RVcQQYQhi5sWzcIK3gc5UJd3wvcDki2DkX4bOecRvDTuM7IIcQg9K45BzPDBakzYQ2gvzr9_yIO7dzFr7C4ajTr-0r8h4HnvQGJ0jxnNM2ypCQ0jVmREfxSykhJSMESwpKYkgQlZRzjLkuGR1GQNM_yH2NSiOA=&lang=python&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), running in a SageMathCell, but only using the standard Python `decimal` module, not Sage.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, I don't know whether is is actually competing. The Euler-gamma can also be seen as the "regularized" sum of all zeta's at the nonpositive integer arguments (mostly expressed in a sum-formula using the Bernoulli-numbers). If I do a convergence-acceleration-method, (in the sense of a Nörlund-matrix-summation) I get the following approximations, where the partial sums are documented in steps of 5.
$ \qquad \small 
\begin{array} {ll|ll} 
k & \text{approx partial sum to k'th term}& k & \text{approx partial sum to k'th term}\\
\hline \\
1&1/2&6&0.576161647582377561685517908649\\  11&0.577642454055878876964082277383&16&0.577256945328427287289300010076\\  21&0.577203007376005733835733501905&26&0.577213676374423017168422213469\\  31&0.577216385568992428628821604406&36&0.577215824990983093761408431095\\  41&0.577215639855185823618977575460&46&0.577215658304198651397646593838\\  51&0.577215664821529245660187000460&56&0.577215664719517597256388852446\\  61&0.577215665026720261633726731324&66&0.577215664986600655216189453626\\  71&0.577215664916609466905818220446&76&0.577215664902581218436870655519\\  81&0.577215664899673837349687879474&86&0.577215664900634540946733895948\\  91&0.577215664901420597291612350155&96&0.577215664901605693627171524946\\  101&0.577215664901606197813305786106&106&0.577215664901564816031433598865\\  111&0.577215664901542872603251577435&116&0.577215664901534551921030743308\\  121&0.577215664901532778454660696838&126&0.577215664901532679657316339069\\  131&0.577215664901532833003775498032&136&0.577215664901532904864265239897\\  141&0.577215664901532914818902560099&146&0.577215664901532899695081822359\\  151&0.577215664901532883268517660911&156&0.577215664901532871664134738564\\  161&0.577215664901532865398778282147&166&0.577215664901532862462629396963\\  171&0.577215664901532861321338522582&176&0.577215664901532860909786316139\\  181&0.577215664901532860775151258773&186&0.577215664901532860715949714001\\  191&0.577215664901532860680839731393&196&0.577215664901532860654520816630\\  201&0.577215664901532860635577825538&206&0.577215664901532860623198773464\\  211&0.577215664901532860615556602981&216&0.577215664901532860611334824284\\  221&0.577215664901532860609026420469&226&0.577215664901532860607850525370\\  231&0.577215664901532860607246781354&236&0.577215664901532860606925091229\\  241&0.577215664901532860606758778390&246&0.577215664901532860606658539051  \\
 \ldots \\
\hline
&&&0.577215664901532860606512090082 \\ &&&\text{(final value as given by Pari/GP)}
 \end{array} $

Well, this might not compete because of the computation effort for the coefficients of the Noerlund summation and also it seems, as if the rate/quality of convergence decreases with the increasing steps, so this should possibly be seen only as a sidenote.

---

*(Reminder as to how to reproduce the behaviour:*

```
\\Pari/GP, using user-defined procedures 
NoerlundSum(1.7,1.0)*ZETA[,1]  \\matrix-function NoerlundSum and ZETA-matrix
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about the best method, however numerically evaluating the integral
$$\gamma = - \int_0^1\!dx\,\ln \ln x^{-1}$$
seems to be pretty efficient.

Comment: Do you mean $$- \int_0^1\!\, \ln \ln x^{-1} dx $$

Comment: @Argon: yes. You can use your favorite numerical method to obtain an approximation to the integral.

Comment: I would then need to compute $\ln \ln \frac{1}{x}$ at several places between $x=0$ and $x=1$ to approximate the definite integral, which again may be quite costly.

Comment: @Aragon: I'm not sure I understand your concern...

Comment: It takes lots of computational effort simply to find the value of $\log$ to a sufficient accuracy.  To do this twice for each summation is very costly and requires much effort.

Comment: Why do you need to estimate $\gamma$ more than once, ever? Once you have it to the desired level of accuracy, you can save the value (and iterate if you need higher accuracy). I cannot imagine why this would take any significant amount of computing power.

Comment: @ronald the other commenters are referring to the computational cost of various operations.  The costs are minute to be sure, but require significant computing power when performed billions (or trillions) of times to compute constants to high degrees of precision.  

As for why one would ever want to carry out those calculations...why do we compute Pi beyond the 14-15 decimal places necessary to given the circumference of the universe to within the diameter of a hydrogen atom? Because it's a mathematical challenge; the methods for computing constants quickly are vastly more complex (and thus)

Comment: @Ronald interesting than the trivial methods.  Moreover, the mathematics that are used to create those non-trivial methods can find application elsewhere.  Finally, the values they generate can be used to test and benchmark supercomputers.  In short, the computation of constants is not nearly as pointless, simple or droll as you imply.

Comment: You've missed my point, I'm afraid. I understand that it's expensive to compute - but it's not necessary to compute the same figure billions of times. That would be a strangely designed computer program.

Comment: @Ronald I believe you've missed the point of the entire question, which is how one can compute $\gamma$ quickly. No-one is saying you should recompute $\gamma$ every time you want it, people here are simply interested in how fast one can compute it.

Answer (score 4):

There is another interesting formula
 $$\small 1- \gamma = \sum_{k=2}^\infty {\zeta(k)-1\over k}$$ 
found in [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) (see eq 123) .
If we simply use approximations to the zetas by truncating their series, and write this in an array
$\small \begin{array} {lll}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
 {1 \over 2^2} &  {1 \over 2^3}  &  {1 \over 2^4}  &  {1 \over 2^5}  & \cdots&{1 \over 2^c}\\
 {1 \over 3^2} &  {1 \over 3^3}  &  {1 \over 3^4}  &  {1 \over 3^5}  & \cdots&{1 \over 2^c}\\
 \cdots &  \cdots &  \cdots &  \cdots &  \cdots & &\\
 {1 \over r^2} &  {1 \over r^3}  &  {1 \over r^4}  &  {1 \over r^5}  & \cdots&{1 \over r^c}\\
\hline
\zeta_r(2)&\zeta_r(3)&\zeta_r(4)&\zeta_r(5)&\cdots&\zeta_r(c)&
 \end{array} $

then we can write an approximation-formula for the Euler $\small \gamma$ 
  $$\small 1-\gamma_{r,c} = \sum_{k=2}^c {\zeta_r(k)-1\over k}$$ 
which depends on the number of rows *r* and the number of columns *c* . Now to reduce the number of coefficients needed to arrive at a good approximation

1. we can use the alternating (column-)sums and convert by the eta/zeta-conversion term
2. additionally we can use Eulersummation for convergence acceleration for the (now alternating) $\small \zeta_r(c) $
3. we can even introduce Euler-summation of (small) *negative* order to accelerate convergence of the sum of zetas (which itself is non-alternating).

If we use all three accelerations, we get a double sum 
  $$\small 1-\gamma_{r,c} = \sum_{k=2}^c \sum_{j=1}^r a_{j,k}{ 1 \over j^k}$$ 
where the $\small a_{j,k} $ contain the factors due to the denominator in the $\small \gamma$-formula and due to the threefold convergence-acceleration.

I did actually implement this in Pari/GP and the surprising result was, that the best approximations were (using order 0.5 in the Eulersummation for the columns and -0.25 for the Eulersummation of the approximated zetas), if roughly *r=c* . Then the number of correct digits were about r/2; so with r=64 and c=64 we get $\small \gamma$ to 31 digits accuracy.
So the effort comes out to be 
$$\small  \text{ # of correct digits} \sim r/2 \qquad \text{ if } r \sim c $$

The ***cost of computation*** of the complete array of zeta-terms is thus in principle quadratic in *d* (the required number of correct digits); for the Euler-sums a vector for the column-acceleration and another vector for the row-acceleration is required whose values can recursively be computed and are thus linear with the number of rows resp the number of columns and thus also linear with *d*. (The convergence-acceleration (1.) by using the alternating sums costs nearly nothing)

Comment: For small enough values of $\zeta$/$\eta$, there is [this algorithm](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P155.pdf) described by Borwein. The Euler-transformed $\eta$ series is a special case of this algorithm; the general method is equivalent to performing Cohen-Rodriguez Villegas-Zagier acceleration to the $\eta$ series (which PARI/GP supports as `sumalt()`).

Comment: @J.M. :true; however it is unknown to me how many operations (terms for the sum) are used by sumalt (I only know it is roughly related to the current float-precision). In the light of some other answers I wanted an explicite description and enumeration of operations which are required for some required correct digits.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this 2013 paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.1420v3.pdf) claiming to offer the first general continued fraction for $\gamma$ with regular pattern. It has ***almost* exponential** convergence. The $\log_{10}$ of absolute error is plotted below:

[image: Euler-Mascheroni error]

The error is of the order of $10^{-17}$ at $100$ steps of the algorithm.

The continued fraction it creates is a little bit complicated, starting with several terms having no apparent pattern:

$$\gamma=\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{4-\cfrac{5}{16+\cfrac{36}{59-\cfrac{15740}{404-\cfrac{1489700}{30422-...}}}}}}$$

The next partial quotents grow very fast in absolute value.

The computation of partial quotents after $5$ is based on a complicated three order reccurence relation, which is described in details in the paper on page 14.

First, we define:

$$q_n=\sum^{n}_{k=0} \left(  \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}  \right)^2 k!$$

Then we define the few initial values $d_1=-1$, $d_2=-2$, $d_3=-5$, $d_4=8$ for a $3^{rd}$ oder reccurence relation for $n \geq 3$:

$$(n-1)(n-2)d_{n+2}=$$

$$=(n-2)(n+1)(n^2+3n-2)d_{n+1}-n^2(2n^3+n^2-7n-4)d_n+n^4(n-1)^2d_{n-1}$$

Then the partial quotents $\frac{a_n|}{|b_n}$ will be defined for $n \geq 6$ as:

$$a_n=-\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}d_n d_{n-2}$$

$$b_n=n^2 d_{n-1}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}q_{n-2}$$

Here is my implementation in Mathematica.

```
A0 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
Af = {{1}, {0}};
Nm = 100;
q = Table[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(n\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Binomial[n, k]\), \(2\)]\ \(k!\)\)\), {n, 1, Nm}];
d = Table[0, {n, 1, Nm}];
d[[1]] = -1;
d[[2]] = -2;
d[[3]] = -5;
d[[4]] = 8;
Do[d[[n + 2]] = ((n + 1) (n^2 + 3 n - 2) d[[n + 1]])/(n - 1) - (
n^2 (2 n^3 + n^2 - 7 n - 4) d[[n]])/((n - 1) (n - 2)) + 
n^4 (n - 1)/(n - 2) d[[n - 1]], {n, 3, Nm - 2}];
a = Table[0, {n, 1, Nm}];
b = Table[0, {n, 1, Nm}];
b[[1]] = 2;
b[[2]] = 4;
b[[3]] = 16;
b[[4]] = 59;
b[[5]] = 404;
a[[1]] = 1;
a[[2]] = -1;
a[[3]] = -5;
a[[4]] = 36;
a[[5]] = -15740;
Do[a[[n]] = 1/4 (-(n - 1)^2) d[[n]] d[[n - 2]]; 
b[[n]] = n^2 d[[n - 1]] + 1/2 (n - 1) (n - 2) q[[n - 2]], {n, 6, 
Nm}];
er = Table[0, {n, 1, Nm}];
Do[A1 = {{b[[n]], 1}, {a[[n]], 0}};
P0 = A0.Af;
A0 = A0.A1;
P = A0.Af;
Pf = N[P[[1, 1]]/P[[2, 1]], 20];
er[[n]] = Log[10, Pf - EulerGamma];
Print[n, " ", Pf, " ", Pf - EulerGamma], {n, 1, Nm}]
ListPlot[er]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm0wf.png) arXiv:1010.1420 [math.NT]

Answer (score 2):

No heavy machinery or special series manipulation required for this. Simple enough to do on a standard scientific calculator.

By applying the [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), one finds that

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}H_b-H_{n-1}-\ln(b)+\ln(n)=\frac1{2n}+\left(\sum_{j=1}^p\frac{B_{2j}}{2j\times n^{2j}}\right)+R_{n,p}$$

and thus, we may derive

$$\gamma=H_{n-1}-\ln(n)+\frac1{2n}+\left(\sum_{j=1}^p\frac{B_{2j}}{2j\times n^{2j}}\right)+R_{n,p}$$

where

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

$$|R_{n,p}|\le\frac{2\zeta(2p)(2p-1)!}{(2\pi n)^{2p}}$$

where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. It suffices to use

$$\zeta(s)<\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\left(1-\frac1{2^s}\right)$$

Or more simply,

$$\zeta(s)<2$$

both for $s\ge2$.

For example, with $n=5$ and $p=4$, we can approximate out $7$ places:

$$\gamma=H_4-\ln(5)+\frac1{10}+\frac1{300}-\frac1{75000}+\frac1{3937500}-\frac1{93750000}+R_{5,4}$$

$$\gamma\approx0.577215664+R_{5,4}$$

where

$$|R_{5,4}|<1.1\times10^{-8}$$

Comment: What does the function $f$ in the linked WP article correspond to in your answer?

Comment: @flawr It corresponds to $1/x$, summed/integrated from $n$ to $b$.