# Question on Macys formula for Euler-Mascheroni Constant $\gamma$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

I think that:

$\gamma = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ~~~ 2H_{n} - H_{n(n+1)}~~~~~~$
(where $H_{n}$ is the $n$-th harmonic number)

is a closed form of Macys $\gamma$ formula:

$\gamma = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ~~~ (1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}-...-\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}-...-\frac{1}{n^{2}+n})$

which I stumbled upon in Will Jagy's comment to the M.SE question:

[What is the fastest/most efficient algorithm for estimating Euler's Constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129777/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-algorithm-for-estimating-eulers-constant-g)

I tried to read the references given to Macys [paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=9386&option_lang=eng), but they appear to be all behind a paywall. My question is, if this closed form is already mentioned in those papers?

Comment: Can you give the bibliographic details for Macy's paper?

Comment: Bib-reference should be this: J. J. Mačys, “On the Euler–Mascheroni Constant”, Mat. Zametki, 94:5 (2013), 695–701

Comment: By the way, it also seems that $\gamma ~ =~\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}~\frac{kH_{n}-H_{n^{k}}}{k-1}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}\geq2$

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the author posted a version on arXiv?

Comment: Did not yet found it on arXiv.

Comment: Does no one have a copy of the paper?

Comment: Another way to write it is:
$
\gamma= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{n}-\sum_{j=n(n-1)+1}^{n(n+1)} \frac{1}{j}\right)
$
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591256/134791

Comment: which leads to a closed form for $\psi\left(z+1\right)$
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357091/re-expressing-the-digamma

Comment: Changing the weight of the last term converges faster (error to $n^{-4}$)
$$lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 2H_n-\frac{1}{6}H_{n^2+n-1}-\frac{5}{6}H_{n^2+n}\right)$$

Comment: and this relates to why $\gamma^2=\frac{1}{3}$
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1613229/134791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\gamma_n=H_n-\ln n=H_n-k\frac{\ln n}k=H_n-\frac{\ln n^k}k=H_n-\frac{H_{n^k}-\gamma_{n^k}}k\iff$$ $$\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(H_n-\dfrac{H_{n^k}}k\right)=\dfrac{k-1}k\cdot\gamma$$

Comment: Thanks for the proof. I will wait for a couple of days, if anybody adresses the original question and if not, accept yours as answer.

Comment: @nyc: [Here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFirstPage.phtml?jrnid=mzm&paperid=9386) is the first page of a Russian version of the article in question, containing the formula. Knowing the meaning of Cyrillic letters, I can confirm that the name there is indeed Ma$\breve{\text{c}}$is.

Comment: Thanks. The closed form formula isn't mentioned on the first page. Could you maybe read any statement in the text on that page, if Macis mentions a closed form?

Comment: @nyc: Unfortunately I don't speak any Russian. :-) I only know the meaning of their letters. But [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/19661/vladimir-reshetnikov) guy might be able to help you... Actually, I just used Google Translate, and wasn't able to find the expression "closed form" there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof for your expression.

Given
$$\gamma=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(H_n-log(n)\right)$$

and
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} log\left( \frac{n^2}{n(n+1)}\right)=0$$

we have
$$lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2H_n-H_{n(n+1)}\right) = lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2H_n-H_{n(n+1)}\right)- \lim_{n \to \infty} log\left( \frac{n^2}{n(n+1)}\right)$$
$$=lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2H_n-H_{n(n+1)}- log\left( \frac{n^2}{n(n+1)}\right)\right)$$
$$=lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2H_n-2log\left(n\right)-H_{n(n+1)}+log\left(n(n+1)\right)\right)$$
$$=2\gamma-\gamma=\gamma$$