# What is the series representation of $\frac{1}{\gamma}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

If [a series representation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constante_d%27Euler-Mascheroni) of ${\gamma}$ The Euler-Mascheroni constant is:$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left[\frac 1 k -\log\left(1+\frac 1 k\right)\right]$ then what is the series representation of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\gamma}$ ?.

Comment: "The series representation" should really be "A series representation" since there's a lot of them

Comment: It is rarely simple to derive a series representation for $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, given a series representation for $\alpha$. And $\gamma$ is the Euler-*Mascheroni* constant.

Comment: There's a regular generalized continued fraction representation of $\gamma$, which trivially is also a representation of $1/ \gamma$, since it's a fraction. The details and the reference to the paper where it was given, are in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1660486/269624)

Comment: A very serious joke: $1/\gamma + 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots$